# Does aws codebuild still support python2.7 runtime?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I maintain a project which developed by python2.7

Now, I want to distribute the project using codecommit, codebuild and cloudformation services.

I run a demo which is using python3.8 runtime environment perfectly,

but if I change the environment to python2.7,

it can't run correctly.

So, I want to know is that does aws codebuild still support python2.7 yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **does not support** 2.7. The supported runtimes are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html#linux-runtimes). For python, you only have 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9.

You can "manually" install python 2.7 in any linux CodeBuild image and use it in your build project. Or you can create a [custom image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html).